# What code snippet should i add in my click functiionality code in that when i hover over the message, it sticks there?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

How can I make the "`tick`" stick there whenever a message is viewed in the chat inbox to show that the message has been viewed?

By now when the message is hovered a confirmation tick appears on each message but it then disappears as you type in the textarea a new message?

```js
/**
 * ClickFunctionality.js
 */

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.fn.notify = function(options) {
    var defaults = {
      type: 'neutral',
      message: 'This is a notification'
    };

    var options = jQuery.extend(defaults, options);
    var notification = '<div class="notify ' + options.type + '">' + options.message + '</div>';
    if ($('.notify').size() > 0) {
      $('.notify').remove();
    }

    $('.channel_post_date').after(notification);
  }

  $("body").trigger();
  $(this).notify({type:'position', message: '<i><img src="js3/t5.png    style="padding-left:7px;padding-bottom:1px;"></i>'});
});
```

```html
<div class="channel_content" id="channel_content">
  <div class="channel_header">
    <div class="channel_header_headline">
      <?php echo message_name($message); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="channel_header_search">
      <input class="channel_header_search_input" id="channel_header_search_input" onkeydown="search()" type="text" value="Search" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Search'){this.value = '';}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value = 'Search';}" />
    </div>
    <div class="channel_header_files" onclick="change_files(); files_only();">
    </div>
    <div class="channel_header_tasks" onclick="change_tasks(); tasks_only();">
    </div>      
    <div class="channel_header_events" onclick="change_events(); events_only();">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanx how can i make the "tick"  stick there whenever a message is viewed in the chat inbox  to show that the message has been viewed because right now when the message is hovered a comfirmation tick appears on each message but it then disappears as you type in the textarea a new message?

Comment: I added your comment to the question